# Emma coverage eclipse plugin, using it into a Java web project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, emma

Recently I installed the Emma-coverage plugin in my Spring Tool Suite IDE, I would like to try testing the code as a Java Application (Further on as JUnit or TestNG) buth the point is that it needs a main class in the configuration, as a web project (actually a Spring project) there is not a main class, so how can I do this? should I create a Servlet? is better using it from maven? any experiences about it?
I will appreciate all of them, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discarded the IDE option, from the external tool seems to be more practice and solve my need.